# "Relative References Must Start With Either "/", "./", or "../"" Error when Using Nodemailer in a Function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodemailer

I am attempting to send an email via JavaScript with the Nodemailer package

When I create a JavaScript file with just this code in it:

```
import { createTransport } from 'nodemailer';
 
function writeMail() {
const transporter = createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: '587',
    auth: {
      user: 'USER',
      pass: 'PASS'
    }
  })
  
  const sendEmail = async (mailOptions) => {
    const { from, to, subject, text } = mailOptions
    
    await transporter.sendMail({
      from,
      to,
      subject,
      text
    })
  }
  
  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'SENDER', 
    to: 'RECEIVER', 
    subject: 'SUBJECT',
    text: 'BODY'
  }
  
  sendEmail(mailOptions)
}
writeMail()
```

The email sends with no issues; however, when I try to run this function from a button click action on an HTML page, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "nodemailer". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Here's how my HTML looks:

```
<script type = "module" src="myFile.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="writeMail()">
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are mixing between runtime environments, server and browser. You should be using ajax or something to invoke the method on the server